# How to change Datagridview row header

Tags: c#, datagridview

The datagridview shows the data nicely, but I want to see numbers sequentially instead of pointers at the rows header.

[image]

As seen in the picture, there is an arrow in the header cell. I don't want like this, When I write the code below, the numbers only appear when the mouse hovers over them.

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows[i].HeaderCell.Value = (i + 1).ToString();
}
```

I want to see it directly in the line headings like in the image directly below

[image]

Comment: add a column for that

Comment: nope I don't want to add a new column. :(

Comment: What does "to the right [...] on the far left" mean?

Comment: Sorry for my english, i mean ">" this

Comment: Oh,  a "right arrow".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can draw the row header yourself:

```cs
private void DataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{
    // Draw only if the cell is the row header: e.ColumnIndex == -1
    // and the row is not the column header: e.RowIndex >= 0
    if (e.ColumnIndex == -1 && e.RowIndex >= 0) {
        bool isSelected = (e.State & DataGridViewElementStates.Selected) != 0;
        e.PaintBackground(e.ClipBounds, isSelected);
        var grid = (DataGridView)sender;
        if (e.RowIndex == grid.CurrentRow.Index) {
            e.PaintContent(e.ClipBounds); // Paints the selection arrow
        }

        var g = e.Graphics!;
        TextRenderer.DrawText(g, $"{e.RowIndex + 1}\u00a0", grid.Font, e.CellBounds,
            grid.ForeColor, TextFormatFlags.Right | TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter);
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

I made the number align to the right and centered vertically. `"\u00a0"` is a non-breaking space that gives the row number a minimal distance to the right edge of the row header cell.

I tried `g.DrawString` and `TextRenderer.DrawText`. The latter one makes text look more consistent with the rest of the grid and draws a sharper text.

[image]